# JavaEE Websphere Liberty No root resource matching request & No valid jdbcDriver

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, jax-rs, websphere-liberty

i need your help ... it s getting me crazy, i try to deploy a very simple application on to a websphere liberty 16.0.0.2 server. My first big problem, the rest api cant be called. Getting the error: No root resource matching request path /admin-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT/api/account has been found, Relative Path: /api/account.

The Code: 
AppREST

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@ApplicationPath("api")
     public class AppREST extends Application {

     public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
         Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
         resources.add(AccountREST.class);
         resources.add(GroupREST.class);
         return resources;
     }
}
```

AccountREST

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import java.util.List;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
@Path("/account")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class AccountREST {

@Inject
private AccountFacade accountFacade;

@POST
public void createAccount(AccountRequest accountRequest){

}

@GET
public List<AccountRequest> getAccountRequests() {
    return accountFacade.getAccountRequests();
}
```

GroupREST is nearly the same to AccountREST.
The web.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">
<module-name>admin-web</module-name>
<display-name>Eportal Registration Admin</display-name>

</web-app>
```

The POM File includes this dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>eportal.registration.admin</groupId>
        <artifactId>admin-models</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>eportal.registration.admin</groupId>
        <artifactId>admin-usecases</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>eportal.registration.admin</groupId>
        <artifactId>admin-models</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>eportal.registration.admin</groupId>
        <artifactId>admin-repositories</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I really cant see the mistake i nearly copy past it from a working project :(

Now second Problem the JDBC Drive. I downloaded the mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.jar from maven central. And added it to the server.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server description="new server">

<!-- Enable features -->
<featureManager>
    <feature>javaee-7.0</feature>
</featureManager>
<httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
              httpPort="9080" />

<applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>

<dataSource id="RegistrationAdminDB" jndiName="jdbc/RegistrationAdminDB">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="MySQLLib"/>
    <properties databaseName="REGISTRATIONADMINDB" serverName="localhost" portNumber="3306"/>
</dataSource>

<library id="MySQLLib">
    <fileset dir="/opt/ibm/wlp/clients/mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.jar"/>
</library>
</server>
```

Getting the error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLNonTransientException: DSRA4000E: A valid JDBC driver implementation class was not found for the jdbcDriver dataSource[RegistrationAdminDB]/jdbcDriver[default-0] using the library MySQLLib. []
at com.ibm.ws.resource.internal.ResourceFactoryTrackerData$1.getService(ResourceFactoryTrackerData.java:113)
```

at startup.

Well i cant find the mistakes but unlucky nothing works :(
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first issue, does liberty successfully deploy the app if you copy the war file to the dropins folder? It will usually give the your URL/port and context root that your app has been started with if the deployment was successful.

With the second issue, have you tried following the steps here? [Configuring MySQL Driver in Liberty](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/t_configuring_liberty_profile_for_my_sql_manually.html)

1. Add the MySQL JDBC driver JAR file to $LIBERTY_HOME/wlp/usr/shared/resources/mysql. If that directory does not exist, create it.
2. Configure the data source in the $LIBERTY_HOME/usr/servers/worklightServer/server.xml file (worklightServer may be replaced in this path by the name of your server) as follows:

`<library id="MySQLLib">
      <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/mysql" includes="*.jar"/>
    </library>`

Comment: Hey Thanks, lessons learned - Dont debug config after 12h work xD i deployed my app into the template folder -.- the code is totally fine, just didnt get updated. The newest mysql connector 6.x.x seems not to work - after changing my config and downgrading the connector it worked. Ty

Comment: Haha, we've all been there mate ;) Glad it's working

Answer (score 0):

In your server.xml you have a `<fileset dir="..."/>` that points to a file instead of a directory.

Try the following for your `<library>` configuration:

```
<library id="MySQLLib">
    <fileset dir="/opt/ibm/wlp/clients"/>
</library>
```